# parsing and updating object position for animation in three js

Tags: animation, three.js

All the tutorials I have read about animating in three.js have been about moving objects in circular or random trajectories. My problem is that i have a 129k lines long .txt file that contains the specific xyz positions of atoms over time. Every iteration starts with:

```
256
Atoms. Timestep: 66000
1 0.702825 2.71217 2.71612
1 16.9592 2.64886 6.79019
1 0.681418 2.68359 10.8911
1 16.96 2.6822 14.9396
1 0.659922 6.77858 2.72442
1 16.9873 6.7709 6.77907
...
```

this repeats up to 256 atoms. Ignoring the first 2 lines, the next 256 lines are the xyz positions of the atoms from the first "frame" of the animation, and there are 500 frames total (500 x 258 = 129000 lines total). I modeled the first frame of my animation by putting the first 256 positions into a separate file and parsing it, now i would like to update the position of my atoms for every next frame using the rest of the document. 
here is the code i used to parse the positions for the first frame:

```
    fetch('Une_image_256_atomes.txt').then(response => response.text()).then(text => {
      const atoms = text.split('\n')  
        .map(line => line.trim())     
        .map(line => line.split(' ')) 
        .map(([size, x, y, z]) => ({ 
          size: Number(size), 
          x: Number(x), 
          y: Number(y), 
          z: Number(z) 
        }));

        for (var i = 0; i < atoms.length; i++) {
            atom = sphere.clone();
            atom.position.set( atoms[i].x, atoms[i].y, atoms[i].z );
            atom.name = "atom";
            scene.add( atom );
            group.push( atom );
        }
```

in which "group" is the array that contains all the atom objects.

1. is it better to cut the long file into 500 smaller files and loop to parse every short file with the same code or should i parse the long file in one go? if it's the latter, how do i iterate within it so that every frame of the animation = the next 256 positions?
2. is there a way to set the time for each frame? Let's say 1 ms if i want the animation to be faster or 10 ms if slower.
3. how do i get the animation running on load of the page without having to click a button first?

Comment: I've given an answer, but please keep in mind: **1)** Multiple questions should be split into multiple posts, especially when the topics of one are unrelated to the topics of others (e.g. parsing a file has nothing to do with timing renders, which has nothing to do with running a script on a page load.) **2)** While your code helps us see how you're approaching the problem, you did not provide anything telling/showing us what you have **tried**.  It's important to try things first, so we can help you with specific problems/errors.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** If memory allows, keep them all in one file, and parse them into a 2D array such that you have a set of 256 positions for every frame. Consider the loop:

```
var i, j;
for(i = 0, i < numberOfFrames; ++i){
    for(j = 0; j < numberOfAtoms; ++j){
        moveAtom(j, framePositions[i][j]);
    }
}
```

**2)** Use intervals ([setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)) to set up timed execution of your position updates and rendering.

**3)** This is as simple as executing a function which parses your data file and starts your interval. It's a common practice in JavaScript, and there are plenty of examples on the web of how to do that.

Comment: so basically framePositions[i][j].x = x position for one atom, framePositions[i][j].y = y, etc.? for the short file i didn't have to consider stopping the parsing every 258 lines since the entire file was 258 lines, how do i loop to get the 2D array though?

Comment: @YujiaDing Correct. For looping through your file, you'll probably need to do it manually, after you split by line breaks (`\n`). You could [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) 258 "line" sub-arrays out of the array returned from the split, and process those. As I said in my comment, _try it_. Make a backup if you're afraid of ruining what you have. Come back and ask more questions if you get stuck.